# How to fix INSERT INTO ... SELECT code inserting many repeat rows?

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, data-warehouse

I have this code that is meant to insert 39 rows into DWPROD, but it inserts 7056 repeating rows. Could anyone help me identify why?

Tried different codes but haven't found a solution yet.

```sql
INSERT INTO DWPROD (DWPRODID, DWSOURCETABLE, DWSOURCEID, PRODNAME, PRODCATNAME, PRODMANUNAME, PRODSHIPNAME)
SELECT dwprodSeq.nextval, 'a2product', p.prodid, p.prodname, pc.categoryname, m.manuname, s.description
FROM a2product p, a2shipping s, a2manufacturer m, a2prodcategory pc
WHERE p.rowid NOT IN (SELECT source_rowid FROM A2ERROREVENT);
```

Expected result: 39 rows inserted
Actual result: 7056 rows inserted

Comment: Well, you have no join conditions between the 4 tables, so you are effectively doing a large cross join.  BTW, your code looks like Oracle, not MySQL, and if so, you should fix your tags.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
FROM a2product p, a2shipping s, a2manufacturer m, a2prodcategory pc
```

returns the *cartesian product* of 4 tables, meaning the product of the number of rows in each of these tables.
If you want to join the tables use proper joins, like:

```
FROM a2product p 
INNER JOIN a2shipping s ON ...........
INNER JOIN a2manufacturer m ON ............
INNER JOIN a2prodcategory pc ON ...............
```

The conditions in the `ON` clauses will restrict the number of rows and maybe you will get the 39 rows that you want.

Comment: What should I put as the conditions in the ON clauses?

Comment: The relations on columns of the tables, something like `p.column1 = s.column2` for the tables p and s if they are related.

Comment: You can find more here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp and other sites. Just google `INNER JOIN`

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to fix this is, keep distinct for the select

SELECT distinct 'a2product', p.prodid, p.prodname, pc.categoryname, m.manuname, s.description

For this you have to keep 2 select one inside another, sequence on the first and above select inside first.

Other way is finding the joining tables matching conditions, but having multiple rows matching each record. Then handling them in inner query